# Using Maven to Deploy to Weblogic Clusters

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, weblogic9.x, weblogic-maven-plugin

org.codehaus.mojo
weblogic-maven-plugin
2.9.1

We're currently using the weblogic maven plugin successfully to deploy to our local WebLogic 9.2 instances.

When we try to deploy to a remote environment we have a problem. We use a two machine cluster, with the admin server and managed server on one machine, and another managed server on a seperate machine.

When your plugin uploads the application to the admin server, it doesn't copy it to the second managed server on the seperate machine. This then causes the second managed server a problem, as it cannot find the application in the location where the admin server saved it on its own machine.

Config below

```
            <configuration>
                <adminServerHostName>${weblogic.adminServerHostName}</adminServerHostName>
                <adminServerPort>${weblogic.adminServerPort}</adminServerPort>
                <adminServerProtocol>${weblogic.adminServerProtocol}</adminServerProtocol>
                <userId>${weblogic.userId}</userId>
                <password>${weblogic.password}</password>
                <upload>${weblogic.upload}</upload>
                <remote>${weblogic.remote}</remote>
                <verbose>${weblogic.verbose}</verbose>
                <debug>${weblogic.debug}</debug>
            <stage>${weblogic.stage}</stage>
                <targetNames>${weblogic.targetNames}</targetNames>
                <exploded>${weblogic.exploded}</exploded>
            </configuration>

<profile>
  <id>localhost</id>
  <properties>
<weblogic.adminServerHostName>localhost</weblogic.adminServerHostName>
    <weblogic.adminServerPort>7001</weblogic.adminServerPort>
    <weblogic.adminServerProtocol>t3</weblogic.adminServerProtocol>
    <weblogic.userId>weblogic</weblogic.userId>
    <weblogic.password>weblogic</weblogic.password>
    <weblogic.upload>false</weblogic.upload>
    <weblogic.remote>false</weblogic.remote>
    <weblogic.verbose>true</weblogic.verbose>
    <weblogic.debug>true</weblogic.debug>
<weblogic.stage>false</weblogic.stage>
    <weblogic.targetNames>AdminServer</weblogic.targetNames>
    <weblogic.exploded>false</weblogic.exploded>
  </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  <properties>
<weblogic.adminServerHostName>******</weblogic.adminServerHostName>
    <weblogic.adminServerPort>9141</weblogic.adminServerPort>
    <weblogic.adminServerProtocol>t3</weblogic.adminServerProtocol>
    <weblogic.userId>******</weblogic.userId>
    <weblogic.password>******</weblogic.password>
    <weblogic.upload>true</weblogic.upload>
    <weblogic.remote>true</weblogic.remote>
    <weblogic.verbose>true</weblogic.verbose>
    <weblogic.debug>true</weblogic.debug>
<weblogic.stage>true</weblogic.stage>
    <weblogic.targetNames>dev_cluster01</weblogic.targetNames>
    <weblogic.exploded>false</weblogic.exploded>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Does a remote deployment through the console works fine?

Comment: Weird then, because your configuration looks fine. Any logs to show?

Comment: The admin server isn't copying the app to the 2nd machine, I don't know why. It has space, permissions ...

Comment: Not a direct answer (hard without traces) but I'd try to get the `weblogic.Deployer` tool working and then replicate the configuration.

Comment: What was the answer to this one? I'm in the same situation. The <weblogic.targetNames> attribute does not work (cannot deploy to a cluster by name).

Answer (score 0):

This may not relate because my experience has only ever been with WebLogic 10 but...

Make sure you have the clustered configured correctly because it should be WebLogic (not Maven or any plugin) which is responsible for distributing a deployed application to each managed server. The maven plugin should only ever deploy to the admin server and WebLogic handles all the other magic to make sure each managed server it knows about also gets the app deployed. I don't think the fact you are using the MOJO is relevant.

Also, ensure you have NodeManager configured correctly and that it is running. NodeManager (at least on WebLogic 10) is responsible for all communication between nodes. It may be the case that you NodeManager process is hung or killed on the managed server which is not getting the application. This is however unlikely if you have tried doing a deploy from the Admin Console which you stated you did try in your comments on the original question.

Hope this leads you in the right direction.